# java.lang.ClassCastException: class sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to class com.sun.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection

Tags: java

Since I updated to Java 11, I am getting an exception which is proving impossible to pin down.

Please note: **The classes the exception mentions are nowhere to be found in my own code**.

The stacktrace only shows which bit of my code meets the problem, but gives no context at all for the actual code (third party) that causes the problem.

This exception has been asked about before in Stackoverflow, but I can only solve the problem if I can find which third party code is causing this and upgrade it, which will (hopefully) mean that I can see the back of it.

The exception is as follows:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl cannot be cast to class com.sun.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection (sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl and com.sun.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

I strongly suspected some very old apache HttpClient classes, and have replaced them with the java.net.http classes (available since Java 11), but to no avail.

The question is: is there a way to find which .jar contains code that uses `HttpsURLConnectionImpl` and `HttpsURLConnection`?

And does anybody know what the rather unhelpful indication that they `are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'` means?

Comment: I think the new name for `com.sun.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection` is `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`. You need to add the full stacktrace to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was coming from **pd4ml**, a java library for producing pdfs.

I updated to the latest version (3.11.5), which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'

It means that class `sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl` is loaded by the bootstrap loader and are loaded as part of the module `base`. This is completely useless information: That module is the core java stuff (`java.lang.String` is in there too), and that loader is the one that loads that stuff. No wonder; `sun.*` classes are implementation details that are part of what all JDKs ship with out of the box. It provides nothing useful whatsoever for fixing the problem.

> The exception is as follows:

There are only two options.

- You forgot to paste the stack trace that follows the stuff you did paste. That stack trace is the important part, and lets you know exactly where to look.
- You have broken exception handling.

I'm guessing it's option 2 - it's a common thing and perpetuated by manual tutorials. The fix is unfortunate: Go through **all** your code and fix the bad code. A search for `.getMessage()` should get you pretty far. It sure sounds like you are doing something like this:

```
try {
  .. code here ..
} catch (Exception e) {
  log.warn(e.getClass() + ": " + e.getMessage());
}
```

or similar. This is always bad - do not just 'log/print' and forget about an exception: You want any exception to be handled, OR thrown onwards. You never want to take an exception whose meaning is not clear as you write the code, and just 'swallow' it. Update your IDE's template settings for generating try/catch clauses; the proper way to write code that just sort of goes; "Exceptions? Um... I do not want to think about those right now / I dont know what they mean / I do know but there's nothing useful I can do about them at this point or I can't fathom how they could occur", which covers most of the time you need to deal with an exception, is like this:

```
try {
  .. stuff ..
} catch (SomethingIDoNotWantToHandleException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("unhandled", e);
}
```

This will ensure that the place you see that error now has the actual stack trace which will then let you know which library you need to update.

Comment: Or in the case of a a code block which only throws RuntimeExceptions, no catch at all (and no try unless you are using try with resources or need a finally)