# Spring boot application failed due to the "cannot be cast to java.util.jar.JarFile"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, java-8

I am trying to bring up the mid-legacy spring boot application in my local which is running in Spring Boot version (1.5.14) / Java version - 1.8.

I did the setup of the application and the following piece of code on start-up failed in the **JarFile line.**

```
@PostConstruct
public void onPostConstruct() throws IOException {
    try {
        JarFile jarFile = (JarFile) getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getContent();
```

**Failed with the error :**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jarFileResourcesExtractor': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class sun.net.www.content.text.PlainTextInputStream **cannot be cast to class java.util.jar.JarFile** (sun.net.www.content.text.PlainTextInputStream and java.util.jar.JarFile are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Anyone faced this issue, I am suspecting this is due to the version mismatch, but not able to figure out.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: Both are ancient.  Try JDK 17 and Spring Boot 3.

Comment: @duffymo I don’t have choice, this application has 3 million lines of code (legacy application), so need to figure out why this class cast issue is happening

Comment: I don't know.  Tough one.  I do know that no one should be counting on classes in a package named sun.net.www.content.text.  True since JDK 1.0.   Where does that come from?

Comment: Maybe this is your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71205583/java-lang-classcastexception-class-sun-net-www-protocol-https-httpsurlconnectio

Comment: No, the problem is in `getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getContent();` ... in your "local" it seems to be different than in "production" (assuming in prod application starts:)

Comment: You've said that you're using Java 1.8 but the exception message and the mention of the `java.base` module tells me that you're using Java 9 or later. Can you clarify the version of Java that you're using?

Comment: Calling `getContent()` on a `URL` always was a pure gambling. It’s a bold assumption that it will return a `JarFile`. Depending on the actual URL, you may create a `JarFile` instance yourself.